# Dynamic load image & Custom Load image using javascript

Tags: javascript, image

Currently working on Loading image dynamic. If the custom image has the path it has to take the custom image not the default one if there is no custom image path are not available it has to load default image in the given ID.

As I am new to Javascript I am trying my below code.

```
var customImageurl = "custom_Image/web.png";
var defaultImageurl = "";
    function loadGraphics(){
        document.getElementById("loadImage").src = defaultImageurl;
    }
loadGraphics();
<div id="loadImage"></div>
```

It was not working kindly help me.

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Mahadevan

Comment: show your html pls i want to check the img tag

Comment: You need to program your logic using `if`s like in your description.

Comment: hi thanks @PM 77-1 can you please help me

Comment: What exactly do you need help with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that a div has no `src` attribute, as in your example you have `<div id="loadImage"></div>`

Your `defaultImageurl` is also empty.

The solution is to use an `<img/>` element:

```
var customImageurl = "custom_Image/web.png";
var defaultImageurl = "";
function loadGraphics(){
    //v-- will not work! 
    document.getElementById("loadImage").src = defaultImageurl;
    //v-- will work given your example conditions
    document.getElementById("loadImage").src = customImageurl;
}
window.onload = function(){
    loadGraphics();
};
<div id="loadImage-wrap">
    <img id="loadImage" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a `src` attribute on a `<div>` element.

Comment: hi

if i give innerhtml for the div also the image was not working

Comment: yes @user3292788  I am new to javascript i am trying something and I have changed src to innerhtml still it was not working kindly help mer

Comment: The only way to associate an image to a `<div>` is to go through the CSS property `background`. But the semantic will be different.
If you want to insert an image in your `<div>` you have to create it first with `document.createElement` or just with the object `Image`. Take a look [at this exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/2cofdfn1/).